# Dimension of $n \times n$ diagonal matrix with characteristic polynomial $(x-a)^{p}(x-b)^{ q}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

What is the dimension of an $n \times n$ diagonal matrix with characteristic polynomial $(x-a)^{p}(x-b)^{ q}$?

Do I have to make distinct cases with as $p + q < n$ and equal to $n$? And if their sum  is equal to $n$, then  dimension is  equal  to $2$, i.e for two elements $a$ and $b$. Am I going on right  lines? Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For any $n \times n$ matrix $A$, the characteristic polynomial is
$$c_A(\lambda) := \det(\lambda I - A) = \lambda^n + \text{(lower order terms in $\lambda$)} ,$$
which in particular has degree $n$.

In general, the degree of the minimal polynomial $c_A$ has degree $\leq n$, and is at least the number of distinct eigenvalues of $A$.

Comment: Sorry i could not understand .

Comment: What do you not understand in particular?

Comment: Here it is given characteristic polynomial and not minimal

Comment: Also as i am seeing this q as the dimension will be number of distinct elements of matrix

Answer (score 1):

A minimal polynomial of a matrix and its characteristic polynomial have the same irreducible factors

So the minimal polynomial of the matrix will be $(x-a)^k(x-b)^l$ where $1\leq k\leq p;1\leq l\leq q$

also note that for two distinct eigen values their eigen vectors are linearly independent

So the dimension will be $k+l$ where $k,l$ are in the given range

Comment: How do u approach this without knowing minimal polynomial

Comment: do you know the fact that i stated at the beginning ?if you know this then the rest is easy for you

Comment: What is meant by irreducible factors .is it same as saying taking one factor( different from others) only with power raised equal to 1

Comment: the factors which are not reducible i.e $f(x)$ can't be expressed as product of $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ where $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ have degree lower than $f(x)$

Comment: so answer here is 2 ?

Comment: at least 2 @tomb_raider

Comment: why atleast 2 ?

Comment: since you have two distinct factors so at least two.rest you have to see my answer carefully

Comment: i am not getting it .can you explain step by step

Comment: all right.see you have two eigen values $a$ and $b$ distinct so eigen vectors are linearly independent.so the eigen space has dimension at least 2 .next find if the minimal polynomial is $(x-a)^l(x-b)^m$ then its dimension becomes $l+m$

Comment: ok but what is the use of dimension of eigen space here .as from question i think the dimension will be number of distinct elements .here there are two a and b .so basis will consist of two elements .so dimension will be two ?Is this not valid ? Also how to write minimal poly from characteristic poly .And why are you doind it here ?Thanks

Comment: you dont have to find it.its a general statement

Comment: ok i have reached upto here that dimension of eigen space will be atlease 2 ,now please continue

Comment: Does question asks for dimension which refer to dimension of eigen space

Comment: you are right,also you have got the idea right.no need for further details.I was just trying to explain it more clearly

Comment: which idea are you saying about ?